# Set css variable with HTML5 color picker in Angular 5?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, css-variables

I have an Angular 5 application with items styled in CSS with CSS variables, as in

```
--color-links: #0000ff;
a { color: var(--color-links); }
```

So, I was trying to wire up an HTML5 color picker to allow changing this variable on the fly.

I saw [this article](https://css-tricks.com/css-custom-properties-theming/) which showcases [this pen](https://codepen.io/keithclark/pen/qbdVJr) where the author is using some simple JS to do something like I am trying to do, but with `document.addEventListener`.  I was trying to come up with a pure Angular/HTML5 method.

So, I created a picker:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="color-picker-link">Link color</label>
        <input type="color"
               id="color-picker-link"
               (change)="setColor()"
               [(value)]="linkColor">
      </div>
```

And in my Component, I create the variable `linkColor` and setting it to `#0000ff`.  That part works, the picker defaults to blue.

```
public linkColor = '#0000ff';
setColor() {
  console.log('value', this.linkColor);
}
```

However, the variable always logs as the original `30000ff` even though the picker obviously changes.

So, what I need to do is get the value the picker was changed to. Not sure why it's not working.

Also, the sample Codepen I linked to above uses this function to set the variable value once retrieved, although I don't think it would work in an Angular app:

```
function setThemeVar(name, value, unit) {
  var rootStyles = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style;
  rootStyles.setProperty('--theme-' + name, value + (unit || ''));
}
```

If I can solve getting the value from the picker on change, and then fire a function passing that retrieved value I can probably figure out the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the selected value from the picker use ngModelChange event with ngModel directive.

```
<input type="color"
               id="color-picker-link"
               (ngModelChange)="setColor($event)"
               [ngModel]="linkColor">

setColor(newColor) {
  console.log('value', newColor);
  this.linkColor = newColor;
}
```