# Angular: change color css variable with color picker input

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I'm using the code [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49697772/set-css-variable-with-html5-color-picker-in-angular-5) to create an HTML5 color input control to change a css variable color.

The picker is

```
<input type="color"
               id="color-picker-link"
               (ngModelChange)="setColor($event)"
               [(ngModel)]="buttonColor">
```

And the TS is

```
  public buttonColor;

  ngOnInit() {
    let styles = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement);
    // set the color picker to match the value in the default css
    this.buttonColor = String(styles.getPropertyValue('--blue')).trim();
  }

  setColor(newColor) {
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color-button-primary-background', newColor);
  }
```

But I want to have multiple color pickers, each changing a difference css variable.  I don't want to create a function for each, but can't figure out how to pass *which* variable to change from the HTML.  Any suggestions?

### Edit

I might have solved it, not sure if this is the best way:

```
(ngModelChange)="setColor($event,'--color-button-primary-background')"
```

and then

```
  setColor(e, which) {
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty(which, e);
  }
```

I confess, I don't get the `$event` thing at all, as in why it returns the `ngModel` value.

Comment: shouldn't your model know?

Comment: I would think so, but I can't figure out how to extract that info in the `setColor` function to set the correct css variable name.

Comment: Did you try to pass an argument to setColor(), that indicates which color picker call the function ?